# multiple if else if with && condition in JAVA8

Tags: java, java-8

I want to convert below code in java 8 best code practice

```
if(i==0 && j==0) {
    return 1;    
} else if (i==0 && j==1) {
    return 2;
} else if (i==1 && j==0) {
    return 3;
} else if (i==1 && j==1) {
    return 4;
}
```

**EDIT:** OP posted as a comment to the question

```
if(counterFlag==0 && priorityEnable==0) { 
    return 0; 
} else if (counterFlag==0 && priorityEnable==1) { 
    return 1; 
} else if (counterFlag==1 && priorityEnable==0) { 
    return 2; 
} else { 
    return 3; 
}
```

Comment: i need to replace this syso with return statement

Comment: if(counterFlag==0 && priorityEnable==0) {
            return 0;
            }
        else if (counterFlag==0 && priorityEnable==1) {
                return 1;
            }
        else if (counterFlag==1 && priorityEnable==0) {
                return 2;
            }
        else  {
                return 3; 
            }

Comment: To be honest, I don't see any specific java 8 feature that would make this better.

Comment: I not sure that is example or not. But for only that code, you can refactor to `return i*2+j+1`

Comment: I would like to point out to (almost) everyone who has answered up until now that OP is not asking for a clever solution, but for a "best practice" solution.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca the “best practice” is to replace this code by a “clever solution”. The alternative is to apply this process to the caller instead, which the OP did not show, as these returned values look pretty much like there will be another similar testing code or switch statement…

Comment: @Holger I respectfully disagree. The best practice (not seeing the surrounding code) is IMHO to leave it as it is. It's perfectly readable.

Comment: I disagree with you both.  [There are no best practices.](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** in your example, you return 3 as a default, so if `i=2` or `j=2` for example you would return `3`. Is that the expected behavior? I will provide examples where the values of `i` and `j` are assumed to always be `0` or `1`

**For your specific example:**

This seems to be a good compromise, it is shorter and easy enough to read:

```
if(counterFlag==0) {
    return priorityEnable == 0 ? 0 : 1;
}
return priorityEnable == 0 ? 2 : 3;
```

**For more complex cases (i.e. 3, 4, or more variables):** 
I'd go for something like this:

```
Map<int[], Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(new int[] {0, 0}, 0);
map.put(new int[] {0, 1}, 1);
map.put(new int[] {1, 0}, 2);
map.put(new int[] {1, 1}, 3);

return map.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getKey()[0] == counterFlag)
        .filter(e -> e.getKey()[1] == priorityEnable)
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
```

**EDIT:**
@Holger pointed out that *"It's a waste to use a HashMap and then search it linearly. Use IntBuffer as key and you can perform a straight-forward lookup via get"*

That is a good point, I tried it out and I think that this is what he meant:

```
Map<IntBuffer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(IntBuffer.wrap(new int[] {0, 0}), 0);
map.put(IntBuffer.wrap(new int[] {0, 1}), 1);
map.put(IntBuffer.wrap(new int[] {1, 0}), 2);
map.put(IntBuffer.wrap(new int[] {1, 1}), 3);

IntBuffer intBuffer = IntBuffer.wrap(new int[] {counterFlag, priorityEnable});
return map.get(intBuffer);
```

Comment: It’s a waste to use a `HashMap` and then search it linearly. Use [`IntBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/nio/IntBuffer.html) as key and you can perform a straight-forward lookup via `get`…

Comment: @Holger never came accross IntBuffers before, I will edit my answer with it

Comment: @Holger I edited my answer with your suggestion, is that what you had in mind? it works and is indeed a lot more efficient lookup

Comment: Yes, that’s it.

Answer (score 4):

The best I can think of<sup>1</sup> for the ORIGINAL problem without being obscure / unreadable is this:

```
if (i == 0) {
    if (j == 0) {
        System.out.println("print something ");     
    } else if (j == 1) {
         System.out.println("print something ");     
    }
} else if (i == 1) {
    if ( j== 0) {
        System.out.println("print something ");     
    } else if (j == 1) {
         System.out.println("print something ");     
    }
}
```

Beware of doing tricky things like combining the numbers to strings and using them as hash keys.  It is expensive, and there are semantic traps.

For the UPDATED problem, there is a neat solution:

```
if (i >= 0 && i <= 1 && j >= 0 && j <= 1) {
    return 1 + i + 2 * j;
}
```

... but I'm not sure I would write that in *my* code.  It is obscure, and that kind of trickiness can prevent the JIT compiler from generating optimal code<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - I do NOT claim this is "best practice".  This is just my opinion.

2 - That might be irrelevant ...</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Map<String,Supplier<Integer>>` like this.

```
Map<String, Supplier<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

    map.put("00",()-> logic1());
    map.put("01",()-> 2);
    map.put("10",()-> 3);
    map.put("11",()-> 4);
```

you can pass every method that it reurns `Integer` as result.

```
private int logic1(){
  //your logic... 
  return 1;
}
```

and use in this way:

```
map.get(String.valueOf(i)+String.valueOf(j)).get();
```

Comment: Sorry I'm nitpicking your answer, but why use a `Supplier` when a simple `Integer` would do the trick?

Comment: May OP wants to have complex function.

Comment: So why stop there? Why not a `Supplier<Supplier<Integer>>`?

Comment: @VinceEmigh  passed a supplier as value since OP can declare a method for each condition. as you know suppliers are lazy and they don't  invoke until you invoke `get` method. see my updated answer!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this too...

```
int value = (i==0 && j==0)?1:(i==0 && j==1)?2:(i==1 && j==0)?3:(i==1 && j==1)?4:null;
```

Comment: this will lead to the coverity issue as null will never reach